# Such + [the] + adj + noun

Tags: determiners

Consider a sentence like

> The method does not need **the** extra parameter.

Now, assume that we want to add "such" to the sentence. What will the result be?

> The method does not need such the extra parameter.
>
> The method does not need such extra parameter.
>
> The method does not need such an extra parameter.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to squeeze the word 'such' in there? It just doesn't belong at all.

Comment: if you really have to use 'such', it goes before the indefinite article - The method does not need **such an** extra parameter.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Why an? Doesn't it change the meaning of the original sentence which had the?

Comment: You can't say 'such the'. After 'such' must be an indefinite article. If you use 'the' (definite article) before the noun phrase 'extra parameter' then there is nowhere for 'such'. Look at your original question.

Comment: Ok but does it convey the same meaning if we replace the with an?

Comment: See excellent answer by CJ Dennis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*such* means "[any] one like this", so it is indefinite ("[any] one"), not definite ("the one").

Your choices are:

> The method does not need **the** extra parameter. (this particular parameter)
>
> The method does not need **an** extra parameter. (any extra parameter, including this one)
>
> The method does not need such **an** extra parameter. (any extra parameter like this one, but possibly a different type of extra parameter)

Using *such* makes the sentence more specific, e.g. it could be a text parameter or a numeric parameter which is not needed, but an extra boolean parameter might be acceptable. Often, you don't need to be so specific and can leave *such* out of the sentence (e.g. the second sentence above), in this case meaning that you don't want any extra parameters, regardless of what kind they are.

Comment: +1 for being correct... but I still don't think 'such' wants to be in there at all. I think it's an 'ELL thing' to try squeezing 'such' into many places it doesn't naturally fit. A lot of my Japanese friends do it all the time; I'm constantly telling them it's not needed.

Comment: @Tetsujin It definitely shouldn't be overused, but it's not incorrect _per se_. It should be used when warranted, and hopefully my answer explains when that is the case.